# Three.js odd striped shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js

Problem manifests in the following way:

[image]

These are my light settings:

```
const LIGHT_POSITION = 50;

    let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xddffdd, 1);
    light.position.z = LIGHT_POSITION;
    light.position.y = -LIGHT_POSITION * 2;
    light.position.x = -LIGHT_POSITION;
    light.shadowCameraFov = 60;
    light.shadow.mapSize.x = 1024;
    light.shadow.mapSize.y = 1024;
    scene.add(light);

    let light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdddd, 1);
    light2.position.z = LIGHT_POSITION;
    light2.position.x = -LIGHT_POSITION;
    light2.position.y = LIGHT_POSITION * 2;
    light2.shadow.mapSize.x = 1024;
    light2.shadow.mapSize.y = 1024;
    scene.add(light2);

    let light4 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xBBBBBB, 0.3);
    scene.add(light4);
```

And my mesh settings:

```
this.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff,
            morphTargets: true,
            morphNormals: true,
            roughness: 0.8,
            metalness: 0.3
        });

        this.model = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.model.castShadow = true;
        this.model.receiveShadow = true;
```

Any ideas why would the shadows manifest this way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are seeing are self-shadowing artifacts due to `mesh.castShadow` and `mesh.receiveShadow` being set to `true.`

You need to adjust `light.shadow.bias` parameter -- a positive or negative value near zero, such as `- 0.01`.

Varying the shadow bias results in a trade-off between "peter-panning" and self-shadowing artifacts.

three.js r.90