# Trouble using toonshader in three js on objects that cast a shadow

Tags: three.js, shader, shadow

I'm creating a sphere that casts and receives shadows with `MeshToonMaterial` but this is giving me an irregular shadow at the darkest section.

Sphere with irregular shadow:
[image: Sphere with irregular shadow]

Closer look at the sphere:
[image: Closer look at the sphere]

The light is:

```
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 18);
light.position.set(-3,6,-3);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
light.shadow.camera.far = 25;
light.shadowBias = 0.0015;
scene.add(light);
```

The sphere is:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh
(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 32, 16 ), 
    new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({color:0xff4444})
);
mesh.position.y += 1;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
mesh.castShadow = true;
mesh.position.set(-2.5, 3/2, 2.5);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(800,400);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

I've tried with other models and shadow map types with similar results.

If I set:

```
mesh.castShadow = false;
```

Then what I get is:

[image: Good looking sphere]

That's pretty much the style I'm looking for, but I'm also needing it to casts shadows.

I would like to avoid using an extra sphere for casting the shadow.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've changed the type of light to `THREE.DirectionalLight `, the trouble did'nt dissapear, but the result improved greatly.

Comment: Likely self-shadowing. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939256/1461008

Comment: Hi, bias is already close to zero, instead of that I played with some values as suggested in the post with the same result.

Comment: The bias should be negative in your case to prevent the self-shadowing artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling receiving shadows on the sphere mesh will prevent it from being rendered with the cast shadows, but it will still cast a shadow on the plane.

`mesh.receiveShadow = false`

However, that means that the sphere won't have any shadows cast on it from other objects, either.

Other than that, it seems like an issue with the way the toon shader handles cast shadows.