# Three.js- My shadows does not show up correctly. aka. lots of black lines everywhere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js, with some of your guy's help I added shadows to my three.js model however when the light hits it creates thousands of lines. Idk if it's because of how bad I made the model. or I have to just change the light. The image is below.

---

[image of thousands of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWgzR.png)

---

---

And The code

---

```
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    60,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.01,
    1000
);
//camera.rotation.x=-20*Math.PI/180;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
document.getElementById('section1').appendChild(renderer.domElement);


window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    camera.position.y =  3.5 +(window.scrollY/400);
})


function mousemovement(event) {
    const mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    const mouseY = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    light.position.x = mouseX * 7 + 1 ;

   light.position.y = mouseY * 4 + 4.5 ;
};

var numberofclicks = 2;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovement);

window.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    numberofclicks = numberofclicks + 1;
    if(numberofclicks % 2 == 0) {
window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovement);
}
else {
window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemovement);
}
});



//GLTF moldal
var loader = new GLTFLoader();

 loader.load("wrktblv2.gltf", function (gltf) {

    gltf.scene.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child.isMesh) {
    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
})
     scene.add(gltf.scene);

});
 
 var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 20);
 light.castShadow = false;
 
 light.position.set(1,10,2);

 scene.add(light);
 
 camera.position.set(1,3.5,9);

 
 
    //const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(light);
    //const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200,50);
    //scene.add(lightHelper, gridHelper);
 
function animate(){
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     renderer.render(scene,camera);      
 }
 animate();
```

---

I tried changing the light strength
and stuff but could not figure it out.

---

Please help.

Comment: You might need to modify the [shadow.bias](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadow#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.bias) value. I believe [this post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shadows-intersecting-on-flat-2-sided-objects/36824) had the same issue, and it would be easier to debug with a live demo. Any chance you could create a simple demo of this issue in a snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48938170/1461008

Answer (score -1):

It is probably the imported mapping. Your geometry/maps have strange edges. For example, both the table top and leg are discolored at the brightest 2/7 of the lengths. Also, the floor changes texture/moire at a 45-degree angle from the rug.

1. Set material type is too basic (try MeshStandard, MeshPhong...)
2. Geometry overlaps too closely (try bias, mapSize...)
3. Tile material is offset, rotated, or repeats (try ClampToEdge, repeat=1...)
4. Face material is backSide or transparent

Comment: I don’t think any of the 4 bullet points would address the issue. Geometry is not overlapping, texture repeating has no effect on shadow acne, and the faces are very clearly not transparent, nor facing the front side. Please be careful about sending the OP on a wild goose chase.

Comment: These are all pertinent points to consider, related to the topic. Yes, in fact, they are. The rug looks like it may shear the floor plane -- I assume one may disagree, which detracts from the OP. But in terms of topical knowledge, double or transparent or flipped faces would affect the issue. Please reassess YOUR criterion and try the first bullet.