# shadow and rippled-texture in threejs

Tags: three.js

I try to apply texture on ground (a THREE.BoxBufferGeometry) , with shadow of a sphere (sphere is animated by Ammo.js)
The presence of shadow seems to depends of two parameters:

- the **shadow.camera** settings of the **THREE.DirectionalLight** :

  thObject.shadow.camera.left = -d;
  thObject.shadow.camera.right = d;
  thObject.shadow.camera.top = d;
  thObject.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
- the **shadow.camera.far** setting :

  thObject.shadow.camera.far = 110;

(it seems to depend of light position regarding shadow projection on ground).

But "playing" with these two settings create the following situation :

- ripples on texture
- shadow or not shadow (see after a part of shadow).

How to set these parameters but not by trial-and-error ?

(This depends of light position too): for exemple if light is not pointing in vertical axle:
pos: { x: -20, y: 35, z: -20 },
lookAt: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },

[image]

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938170/three-js-odd-striped-shadows/48939256#48939256

Comment: Good ! it needs tuning, but it is a solution for me. Thanks a lot.